# Am I surfing the deep web right now?

Tags: security

How do I know Tor is working on my device?  Is there any way I can know that my whatsapp is routed via Tor?

Comment: Lots but they're extensively technical and possibly beyond your abilities (since you're asking the question, it seems likely). Your best option is to set it up so that it either uses Tor or can't connect at all. Also note you'll never be anonymous using whatsapp, it's linked to your phone number.

Comment: Please try to ask one question at a time. From your question it is unclear, what device you use, what software you have installed etc. Please write a good, specific question. This will help you to get good answers.

Answer (score 2):

So - step by step - to your questions:

- *How do I know Tor is working on my device?* If it's in `top` and in log files you've seen line like `Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.` and after that line `Bootstrapped 100%: Done` - it means that full bootstrap is completed and your Tor instance is up&working. The question is *how it works* after that - look into your `torrc` to answer this question
- *Is there any way I can know that my whatsapp is routed via Tor?* The only way to prove it in 100% is to watch your app *without Tor* and then *with Tor* and make sure that app traffic is not coming straight into network. Wireshark and tcpdump are your best friends here